# Firebase Hosting Vue.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting

I am trying to host my **Vue.js** app on **Firebase** and have been running into problems. I can run the app fine locally on my machine but when I deploy to **Firebase Hosting**, **index.html** seems to load but the files under **/static** don't seem to load.

[image: See this]

I get the following **error message:**

> GET
>   https://hostname.com/static/css/app.f6523a21105b673f23ff46cfd6d47a69.css
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404

My firebase.json :

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        { "source": "/notification", "function": "handleCalendarNotification"}, 
        { "source": "/viewTask/**", "destination": "/dist/index.html"}
    ]
  }
```

My vue.js application uses the /viewTask rewrite.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Firebase support and it turns out that this was a Firebase problem and not a problem with my code. They have fixed it and it is working fine now.